# Managing Create & Update of Kubernetes Deployment in CI/CD pipeline Implementation

Tags: kubernetes, continuous-deployment

Currently I am trying to implement demo for CI/CD pipeline using SVN , Kubernetes and Jenkins. For kubernetes deployment, I created deployment and services.And for making deployment I am using `kubectl apply -f` command for both deployment inside my Jenkins deployment step.

Like the following ,

```
stage ('Test Deployment')
        {
             steps
                {
                    sh 'kubectl apply -f deployment/testdeployment.yaml'
                    sh 'kubectl apply -f deployment/testservice.yaml'
                }
        }
```

and service.

For each commit to my SVN repo will trigger this jenkins pipeline job and will execute the commands. After modifying any changes in code the same `kubectl apply` command is executing.

Here my confusion is that ,

1. Can I use `kubectl apply` command is for updating the existing deployment ?
2. Or Do I need to use the command `kubectl rollout restart` ?

For continuous deployment process in CI/CD pipeline implementation , Which command I need to use in my Jenkinsfile for updating the deployment when commit is made to SVN repository?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the Kubectl apply command as long as the name of resources in the deployment and service file has not changed. From the [Kubernetes book](https://kubectl.docs.kubernetes.io/pages/app_management/apply.html),

> Apply is a command that will update a Kubernetes cluster to match
>   state defined locally in files.
>
> ```
> kubectl apply
> ```
>
> Fully declarative - don't need to specify create or update - just
>   manage files

The parameters relating to rolling deployment such as how many pods should be available and how many can be taken out of active deployment you can check [this documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/#rolling-update-deployment).